# Django doesn't change language when visiting URL with language code

Tags: django, django-i18n

I'm facing a weird situation when trying to change language after appending the language code to the url

```
example -- domain.pt/en
```

If I visit the site normally throught the domain without the language code appended, it works perfectly, I'm able to change language without problem.

If somehow I copy the link and paste it on the browser, the language switcher stops working.

```
example -- domain.pt
```

I have translated a few Django websites so far and found out this happens on all of them.

**#urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
      path('i18n', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
  path('', include('base.urls')),
  prefix_default_language=True,
)
```

**template**

```
<form id="lang-switcher" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value"{{ redirect_to }}">
  <select class="language_selector" name="language" id="" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
  {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

  {% for language in languages %}
  <option value="{{ language.code }}" {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected {% endif %}>
    {{ language.code }}
  </option>
  {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Lisbon'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]

LANGUAGES = [
    ('pt', 'Português'),
    ('en', 'Inglês'),
    ('es', 'Espanhol'),
    ('fr', 'Francês'),
    ('de', 'Alemão'),
]
```

A real-world example of this issue would be like, copying the link, sharing it with someone and the person not being able to change the language of the website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's pretty wierd but, it is working for me perfectly !

Comment: @KhushalJangid try copying this http://157.230.188.234/de/ and try changing language. Is it working fine on yours? Then maybe there's something wrong on my side...

Comment: It's working totally fine  !